# 2000 Focus won't crank after electrical repair

Tags: electrical, ford, focus

OK so a guy I know had this car. He put to big a fuse in it because it kept blowing the fuse for taillights and dash lights. Melted wires coming from headlight switch. Got those separated. Still popping fuse for taillights and dash lights. But it's now starts up and everything else is fine. 
Was reading some where that the wires to the hatch could break and short out where they bend. Bingo , lights fixed. Now everything comes on like it should. But now it won't turn over. 
Won't click just power up that's it.

Comment: Unfortunately, you haven't given us enough information to even start a diagnosis for you yet. What exactly did you do to fix the dash/tail lights (I'm assuming you did fix them?)? Do any of the lights come on now (is battery working and charged)? Any other information? We need some help here if you'd like us to help you.

Comment: I tried to explain it different.  But yes everything works great . Except now it won't turn over. I don't get it. I drovery it home , fixed the lights. Now no start. I'm bummed

Answer (score 1):

So, the problems may be related – or they might not be. It's an easy trap to fall into, assuming that the problems must be related. So, I think the thing to do is to approach the starter problem from "first principles" and see what seems to be causing it.

The very first thing that I would check is the battery voltage. The starter and its solenoid draw a **lot** of current when they operate. If the battery is low, it won't be able to deliver the necessary current and, if it is low enough, nothing will happen. With a bit more current available you'll get clicking from the solenoid, a bit more will get you an attempt to crank, and so on…

A battery that is too low to get any response out of the starter may have enough power to supply the smaller loads so that it appears as if the battery is good. A fully charged battery should be at about 12.6 V, anything less is suspicious. If the battery is low, try a jump start or charge it and try again. If you don't have a volt meter, assume that the battery is low.

Once you confirm that the car will start (or not) with a full battery you can get on to the next step. I'm going to assume that it will start. The most likely problem is that you've still got some residual damage from the melted wires at the headlight switch or that there may be damage that you missed at the rear hatch. If you have a meter the easy check is to measure the draw on the battery when the car is off. It should be only a few milliamperes. An easy way to measure is by pulling fuses on at a time and then measure by putting the meter probes where the fuse was.

If you don't have access to a meter, check your work at the headlight switch and the rear hatch carefully. Or do a test by pulling the fuse that used to blow and seeing if that cures the won't start problem – if it does then you know where the problem lies.

Comment: Sir. I've charged the battery put jumper cables on it for 30 minutes. Still no crank no start. I drove the dang thing home. I'll go over my wires again. And let you know. Thank you

Comment: Interesting… Have you actually measured the voltage? The next thing that I would do is to actually check that there is voltage at the coil terminal of the starter (the one on the solenoid coming from the ignition switch) when you try to start. Since you're getting absolutely nothing and there has been damage to the wiring it could be that there is more damage yet to be found. Try to focus on the facts that you can verify. If the starter doesn't run there are very few options: no signal from the switch, a low battery, or a failed solenoid or motor, or just maybe, no you've lost the ground.

Comment: OK so there's a small ground wire that goes to the battery. I obviously had missed in my haste.  Hooked it up, car started right up. Drove it around the block. Turned the key off pulled it out . Car still running . I understand plugged the ignition switch.  Still running. Pulled a main fuse under the hood. Car died. Put fuse back in. All the little lights Come on the dash. Remember the key is off and out. GRRRRRR.....